# How to initialize R function during first run or whenever input changes

Tags: r, variables, static

I'm new to R and have some trouble of understanding so called "envirionments" and way to use them properly. What I miss a lot in R language are static variables (like in Java).

I'm writing a program with couple of functions that will need to initialize during first run. To achieve this for each function I've created new environment which will be only accessed by this particular function (for example "f1" will be only accessed from inside "myfunction1").

What I don't like about my solution is that there is some additional code outside of function body and it's not too readable. Is there any simpler way to achieve the same? And if yes then it would be nice if you could provide me with modified example to show me how it works. Thank you.

```
f1 <- new.env()
f1$initialized <- FALSE
f1$o <- NULL
f1$length <- NULL
f1$compute

myfunction1 <- function(x) {
  if(f1$initialized == FALSE){
    f1$initialized <- TRUE
    f1$compute <- 2*pi^2+3
  }
  if(is.null(f1$length) || f1$length!=length(x)){
    f1$length <- length(x)
    if(f1$length==2) {f1$o<-read.table("data_1.txt")}
    else {f1$o<-read.table("data_2.txt")}
  }
  print("Lets print something!")
  return(f1$o * f1$compute * x + 1000)
}
```

Comment: You might find the functions `exists` and `assign` to be of use when working with environments in this way

Comment: OTOH, unless you need to hide `f1` from the global environment, why bother?  You could just as easily (I think...) put a couple `load` or `source` calls inside `myfunction1` to get whatever objects from a saved file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with Java then maybe using `RefrenceClasses` would be a good way to go. This seems to do what you are looking for:

```
myclass <- setRefClass('myclass', fields = list(initilized = 'logical',
                                 o = 'data.frame',
                                 len = 'numeric',
                                 compute = 'numeric'))

#constructor
myclass$methods(initialize = function(initialized, len){
initilized <<- initialized    
len <<- len    
})

#method
myclass$methods(myfunction1 = function(x){
if(initilized == FALSE){
    initilized <<- TRUE
    compute <<- 2*pi^2+3
}    
if(is.null(len) || len != length(x)){
    len <<- length(x)
    if(len==2) {o <<- read.table("data_1.txt")}
    else {o <<- read.table("data_2.txt")}
}
print("Lets print something!")
return(o * compute * x + 1000)
})

obj <- myclass$new(FALSE, 0)
obj$myfunction1(2)
```

Check out `?ReferenceClasses` for information on what's going on here (much more OOP styled and has some support for class inheritance, which sounds like what you want anyway).